# How can I scale (x-axes) and shift data within array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of data that represents some signal **f(x)**. If there is a way to perform operations which gives me in result an array of **f(ax + b)** by using only first array?

For "+ b" shifting part I use numpy.insert to insert array of zeros to shift signal left or right, but can't figure how to do f(ax). Please keep in mind that I do not want to a*f(x) and simple multiplication of array by constant is not an option.

Edit: Unfortunately I have no access to function that generated first array, I think that resampling functions are the ones that will solve rescalling issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This sounds like a reasonable question, but it makes a huge difference if you can post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), even for an array with just a few elements. It shows where you're at. Cheers!

Comment: without knowing what the function is I do not think it is possible

Comment: @sai I might have known, I think that resampling functions will solve this rescalling problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the array there are several solutions, the simplest is to access the array `f as f[a*x+b]` and checking if that is a valid index. Here is a code that creates the shifted array:

```py
import numpy as np
def scale_shift(f, a , b):
    i = np.arange(len(f))*a+b
    y = f[i[(0<=i) & (i<len(f))]]
    return y

n = 10
f = np.random.rand(n)
print(scale_shift(f,2,1))
```

Note that the length of the new array will depend on the shift. You can use `%` if you want to wrap around the boundaries

Comment: Thank you, your previous solution with np.fromiter was also very nice. I digged further and think that resampling tools are things I was looking for. Yours is very good for array of integers. Kudos!

Comment: Please update once you have a solution, I am curious to see what tools are available for resampling.

Comment: The most common in usage is scipy.signal.resample, although others pointing some disadvantages of using it, I need to test it with my case.